# Aurelia: How to build a main menu with some dropdown menu items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, aurelia

I am new to aurelia framework. I try to build a main menu with total 7 items. The first 4 items should be top menu items and the last 3 in a dropdown. I work with bootstrap 3.

the router config in the app.ts looks like:

```
config.map([
  { route: ['', 'Buchungen'],
    name: 'Buchungen',
    moduleId: './buchung/app-buchung',
    nav: true, title: 'Buchungen',
    settings: {img:'./img/ic_tab_buchungen_white.png',t:'main_Buchungen',class:'fa fa-money'}},
  { route: 'Konten',
    name: 'Konten',
    moduleId: './konto/app-konto',
    nav: true,
    title: 'Konten',
    settings: {img:'./img/ic_tab_konto_white.gif',t:'main_Konten',class:'fa fa-university' }},
  { route: 'Bilanz',
    name: 'Bilanz',
    moduleId: './bilanz/app-bilanz',
    nav: true,
    title: 'Bilanz',
    settings: {img:'./img/ic_tab_bilanz_white.gif',t:'main_Bilanz',class:'fa fa-balance-scale'} },
  { route: 'Erfolg',
    name: 'Erfolg',
    moduleId: './erfolg/app-erfolg',
    nav: true,
    title: 'Erfolg',
    settings: {img:'./img/ic_tab_erfolg_white.gif',t:'main_Erfolg',class:'fa fa-line-chart'} },
  { route: 'Chart',
    name: 'Chart',
    moduleId: './child-router',
    nav: true,
    title: 'Chart',
    settings: {img:'./img/chart_line32.png',t:'menu_chart',class:'fa fa-area-chart'} },
  { route: 'export',
    name: 'export',
    moduleId: './child-router',
    nav: true,
    title: 'export',
    settings: {img:'./img/ic_menu_export.png',t:'menu_export', class:'glyphicon glyphicon-log-out'}},
  { route: 'option',
    name: 'option',
    moduleId: './child-router',
    nav: true,
    title: 'option',
    settings: {img:'./img/ic_menu_export.png',t:'menu_option', class:'glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal'}}
]);
```

the nav-bar.html looks like:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="aaccounting-navigation-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="${row.isActive ? 'active' : ''}">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#aaccounting-navigation-navbar-collapse.in" href.bind="row.href" >
          <i class="${row.settings.class}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span t.bind="row.settings.t">${row.title}</span>
        </a>
      </li>
```

In the above html there will be 7 menu items in a row, but I like to make the dropdown menu like:

```
<li>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        </ul>

      </li>
```

How can I do that with aurelia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, this answer is helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38444441/4921289

His suggestion is to add properties to your route configuration settings properties (what you already did) to distinquish between dropdown entry or main entry.

Comment: Yes that is the solution (configRouter method).
Thank you.